# PivotFields.AutoGroup works for few but doesnt work for few

Tags: excel, vba

I understand VBA can be tricky at times, but I don't get this.
This piece of code works perfectly fine on my machine.

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(PivotTableName).PivotFields("CalendarWeek")._
 Autogroup
```

But on my friend's machine, it constantly throws an error:

```
Run-time error '438':
Object doesn't support this property or method
```

How can it work fine on one machine but does not on another?

Comment: What version(s) of Excel? Looks like AutoGroup was introduced in Excel 2016.

Comment: My friend is on 2013. And I'm on Version 2102

Comment: There's you answer. 2013 doesn't support AutoGroup. Welcome to writing backwards-compatible code.

Comment: Ah. Is there an alternative solution to this?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do so hard to recommend an alternative.